# Step-up converter generating too much voltage

Tags: dc-dc-converter, boost

I have the issue that I want to convert 5v DC to 12V DC.
I have several 5v to 12v step-up converter at my hands which all output around 15v without any load connected.
Now I heared these need a minimum load to get to their specified level, I tried to connect them to the circuit but still got around 14v.
Its just connected to a cheap 433MHz RF module that doesn't use much current.

What is the best way to increase my load a little to get to the desired 12v? The datasheet doesn't specify any specific current level.
Or can it even be a completey diffrent issue?

Datasheet: http://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/194/SIM1-0512-SIL4-pdf.php

Comment: It's not unusual for those things to require a 10% or so load to output close to the normal voltage. Try a 1K 1/4W resistor. Or a 12V LDO as Andy suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not add a low dropout 12 volt voltage regulator instead of loading the output with resistors. It's likely to produce less heat. This will only work for very light loads like the one suggested and might keep spurious switching noise (from the boost converter) from interfering with the RF circuits and get better performance.

Comment: How would that get me from 5v to 12v?

Comment: He's suggesting adding the low dropout regulator after the boost regular you currently have.  So it will take 15V --> 12V

Comment: Ooh I see, that of course makes a ton of sense.
Not sure why I haven't thought of that earlier..